# can I use two access tokens for a single facebook FQL / graphAPI query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

For example, I want to run this graph api query:

```
/userA/mutualfriends/userB&access_token=what do I put here?
```

the query above should give me the mutual friends of userA and userB, so how to supply both access tokens for userA and userB?

Answer (score 3):

We do not need to have accesses token for both the users.

We just need to have a access_token to the **userA**'s friends. by doing that u have access to the mutual friends of any friend of userA. Try the [Graph Explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) where you can get the access token 
[image: Get Access Token] 
Below is the snapshot of the Select permission from Graph Explorer Page

After clicking on get access token a popup will appear which should look like the below image.

Select **user_friends** from the popup

[image: Sample Image]

now run the your query **/userA/mutualfriends/userB&access_token=access_token**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use **2** tokens in any query.

Btw, you **don't** need 2 access tokens for your problem! You just need the access token of any of the user. For eg: if you use the access token of User-A, query-

```
/<user-A>/mutualfriends/<user-B>?access_token=<access_token-of-user-A>
```

[ If you are confused of how to test this in the Graph API Explorer, simple clear the access token field and explicitly write `&access_token=`]